# will using label as operand that is not yet defined cause an error

Tags: assembly, mips

For example

```
      .word loop
      loop:
```

My question is that in that example, will assembler throw an error even if the label will be defined in later code?

Comment: No. But why haven't you tried it?

Comment: @Jester, I am building an assembler right now. Just wondering if that is valid

Comment: I suspect it still would have taken less time and effort to just try it ... anyway, as I have said, that's valid (in most assemblers).

Comment: If it's your own assembler it's up to you to decide whether forward references will be supported or not (though writing assembly code without them would be quite problematic).